# No graba en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

perdon la molestia, tengo un archivo socios.php para poder grabar en una BD, nombre, apellido, mail, fecha de nacimiento y cargar una foto .jpg. La misma debe guardarse con un codigo generico o incremental en la BD y el archivo localmente o en el servidor, pero no conecta, lo tengo asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<?php
        include "conexion.php";
        include "header.php";

$con = conectar();
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM archivos";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql2); ?>

</br>

<h1><center>Ingresar Socio</center></h1>
                <form action="grabar.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Mail" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="Fecha Nacimiento" id="Fecha Nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" required>
                    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>

    </head>
```

Despues tengo grabar.php:

```html
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();

    $nombre_socio=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido_socio=$_POST['apellido'];
    $mail_socio=$_POST['mail'];

$sql2= "INSERT INTO archivos VALUES(

    '$nombre_socio', 
    '$apellido_socio', 
    '$mail_socio')";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

if ($query) {
    header('location: index.php'); 
    exit();
    
    }
    else {

    }

?>
```

Y asi tengo la base de datos hecha:

[image: Base de datos]

Comment: Porque dices que te no conecta? te arroja un error en la bd? intentaste verificar que estas colocando las credenciales correctas? tu otro error esta en el INSERT, ya que deberia ser INSERT INTO archivos (campos de la bd a insertar) VALUES (valores a insertar)

Comment: Gracias ante todo, ahora me arroja este error:

Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intermedio\grabar.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intermedio\grabar.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intermedio\grabar.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

Hola denuevo (soy el que te paso en un antiguo comentario el codigo del crud), veo que aun no estas bien en cuanto a estructura y todo, pero bueno, copie tal cual tu codigo y ami me dejo ingresarlo, imagino puede ser de tu base de datos, esas letras mayusculas que usas Apellido (tienes apellido en tu codigo en minuscula) prueba si con eso funciona,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para en cuanto al codigo que use fue el mismo como te digo solo que le puse el id (como l ocree rapido no le puse autoincrement)

grabar.php

```html
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
$con=conectar();

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $mail=$_POST['mail'];
    $fecha_nacimiento=$_POST['Fecha_Nacimiento'];
    $foto=$_POST['foto'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO socios VALUES(
    '$id', 
    '$nombre', 
    '$apellido', 
    '$mail', 
    '$fecha_nacimiento', 
    '$foto')";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($query) {
    header('location: index.php'); 
    exit();
    
    }
    else {

    }

?>
```

socios.php (asi le puse)

```html
<?php include("conexion.php");
$con = conectar();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM socios";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!--     estilos bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!--     estilos bootstrap -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--     Tabla para ingresar -->
            <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <h1>ingresar Socios</h1>

                <form action="grabar.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Id" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Mail" required>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control mb-3" name="Fecha_Nacimiento" id="Fecha_Nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" required>
                    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>


            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

igual verifica tu archivo de CONEXION.php

```html
<?php function conectar(){

    $host = "localhost";
    $user ="root";  /*   tu usuario del server */
    $pass ="";  /*   tu contraseña del server */
    $bd ="prueba";  /*   tu base de datos del server */
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($con,$bd);
    return $con;
}
?>
```

revisa bien este archivo que es el que hace la conexion a todo lo demas , me dices si era problema con la base de datos (la mayuscula) de todas formas anexo la base que cree de manera rapida para ver si era eso igual

```html
CREATE TABLE `socios` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `foto` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `socios`
--

INSERT INTO `socios` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `mail`, `fecha_nacimiento`, `foto`) VALUES
(1, 'Jesus', 'Jesus', 'Jesus@jesus.com', '2022-11-02', 0x3331333332373833315f313939373737363335373038383533305f383933383234323633393537363230333335305f6e2e6a7067),
(2, 'Jose', 'Jose', 'Jose@Jose.com.mx', '2022-11-30', 0x3331333332373833315f313939373737363335373038383533305f383933383234323633393537363230333335305f6e2e6a7067),
(3, 'Dell', 'Dell', 'Dell@Dell.com.mx', '2022-11-30', 0x3331333332373833315f313939373737363335373038383533305f383933383234323633393537363230333335305f6e2e6a7067),
(4, 'Hershey', 'Hershey', 'Hershey@Hershey.com.mx', '2012-01-17', 0x3331333332373833315f313939373737363335373038383533305f383933383234323633393537363230333335305f6e2e6a7067);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Quedo excelente! era un tema con las mayusuculas y minusculas. Te agradezco muchisimo.

Comment: si, mucho cuidado con esas cosas, mas que nada en servidores linux (cuando subas tu pagina a un server por lo general usan linux) , presenta muchos problemas, sugiero evitar usarlas para evitar problemas en el futuro, y trata de poner siempre nombres con _ , ejemplo : fecha_nacimiento , igual te ayudara en el futuro a errores muy sencillos que uno se quiebra la cabeza y nunca sabe que es(hasta que recuerda eso ) saludos!

Comment: Saludos @DiegoRanieri, si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada. ;)